# Deciding when to use handle functions and when to encapsulate inside a button in React

Tags: reactjs, function, event-handling, handle

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm trying to understand when it's a good idea to use "handle functions" in my code and when it's better to keep things simple and just put everything inside the button, for example. Can someone help me understand the differences and when it is appropriate to use each approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this choice to be about readability of code, conventions of the codebase, and personal preference.
If it's more than a few lines, I would separate the function from the button to not bloat the JSX.